# Setting Lifecycle configuration for S3 Buckets in YAML file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, s3-lifecycle-policy

I'm trying to set a Life cycle configuration for my S3 buckets to expire after 90 days. However, I'm getting an error saying "Property Status cannot be empty" when pushing my CFT stack.

I tried setting a lifestyle config, and putting the expiration in days onto that, but it seems to be failing.

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Creates S3 Bucket

Resources:
 TestBucket:
 Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
 Properties:
   BucketName: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-test"
   AccessControl: Private
   LifecycleConfiguration:
    Rules:
    - Id: DeleteContentAfter90Days
      Prefix: ''
      Status: Enabled
      ExpirationInDays: '90'
```

I'm getting "Property status cannot be empty" and an update rollback when I check my status in the console.

Answer (score 16):

```
Status: 'Enabled'
```

Status should be string value as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-lifecycleconfig-rule.html#cfn-s3-bucket-lifecycleconfig-rule-status)

Here is a working example of LifecycleConfiguration:

```
LifecycleConfiguration:
    Rules:
      - Id: DeleteContentAfter1Day
        Status: 'Enabled'
        ExpirationInDays: 1
```

Answer (score 5):

`ExpirationInDays` should be a number, not a string

Answer (score 2):

Cloudformation can't take null values, remove this line - Prefix: ''